# OpenAL - how to play unattenuated sound effects?

Tags: openal

I'm using OpenAL in my iPhone project to create sounds that attenuate when farther away from the listener.

However - I also want to play some sound effects that shall not be attenuated by distance.

So far I solved that by using stereo sounds, which don't get attenuated. But now I'm adding a lot of voiceacting which takes quite some space - so I want them to be mono and now have the problem again that they get attenuated by distance.

My next solution was to set "AL_MIN_GAIN" of the source playing the voice samples to 1.0, but this seems to be working only on the simulator, not on the device.

Are there other ways to play sound effects with openAL that shall not be attenuated by distance?

Comment: Using stereo sounds sounds like a great way to get around this.

Answer (score 5):

```
alSourcei (sourceName, AL_SOURCE_RELATIVE, AL_TRUE);
alSource3f (sourceName, AL_POSITION, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
alSource3f (sourceName, AL_VELOCITY, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

And then the source should stay at the listener's position.

Comment: This doesn't _actually_ work if you move the listener. I believe `AL_SOURCE_RELATIVE` this must be for _initial specification of the sound source position_, but if the listener moves, _the sound source does not move with it_ (so it still acts like a 3d sound)

Comment: Also, velocities are not done relatively, so you would actually have to set the velocity of the source (and update it every frame) to stop the doppler effect from happening

Comment: [Excellent post discussing my first comment here](http://openal.996291.n3.nabble.com/AL-SOURCE-RELATIVE-behavior-td4190.html)

Comment: __Actually no__, this way works fine.  You just have to make sure _not to move the sound source again_.

Answer (score 1):

You can try opening a second context that doesn't have a distance model. I'm not sure if iOS supports multiple contexts or not though...

Alternatively, just keep your "voice" sources at the same position as the listener.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
alSourcei(id, AL_DIRECT_CHANNELS_SOFT, 1)
```

`AL_DIRECT_CHANNELS_SOFT` macro is defined in `<AL/alext.h>`